# Need to change date formate to date (YYYYMMDD) format

Tags: stored-procedures

Here the requirement is to convert sysdate to in to YYYYMMDD in date format. Here issue it converts this in string but I need this to convert in date format in YYYYMMDD form.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate-1),'YYYYMMDD') cdr_date from dual;
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to help if you mentioned what database you were using in your post or at least your tags. However based on the to_char function you are using I am assuming oracle. If that is right then the below code should help you out. I found this by simply googling oracle date format and going to the first link which is:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

```
Select to_date(trunc(sysdate-1),'YYYYMMDD') cdr_Date from dual;
```

Comment: Thx for you reply this oracle database  ... thats i already tried but its giving error as its not specified to_date format , error msg -

Comment: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Comment: I am not familiar with oracle myself so i guess leave it to people that are. I would update your question both with your error and the fact you are using oracle and what version of it you are using.